# Installation of webapps Google+ and Grooveshark

Tags: firefox, webapps, firefox-extensions, grooveshark, google-plus

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm having trouble installing some webapps (especially Google+ and Grooveshark). The firefox is in its most recent version and offers no option to install them.

Thank you for your attention and help.

Comment: Please give more detail when asking questions of this nature. What kind of trouble? Do some apps work? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Does Firefox offer to install other webapps, such as Launchpad or LinkedIn? If so, then are you sure you haven't already installed G+ and Grooveshark? If not, check your Extensions and see if the Ubuntu extension for the web apps (I think it's the "Unity integration" one, but I'm not at an Ubuntu machine right now, so I could be mistaken) is installed, enabled, and up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe see here:
http://www.iloveubuntu.net/unity-grooveshark-scope-01-updated-previews-support

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.